# words or phrases to describe people who value relationships

Tags: word-request

What are any vocabulary or phrases to describe the kind of people who value relationship (with family, friends, colleagues...)  more over other things, work, success, etc. ?

Comment: Does this answer you question?: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450953/adjective-to-describe-someone-who-values-and-nurtures-their-interpersonal-relati

Comment: This may wind up being a matter of opinion.  I don't know that we have an actual, agreed upon, word.  I would describe such person as a **loving** person but that is just my opinion.  Dhanishtha's link is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps consider the term "family man" (for a man, obviously) which describes a man who's family is of major importance in their life.

For a more gender-neutral term, just as a person who puts their career first is called "career-minded", someone who puts their family first is "family focused".

Otherwise, perhaps consider the word **loyal**, or a synonym of it. A loyal person sticks to their friends and family, which *demonstrates* they value them rather than simply saying that they do.